# My SP cant store an unicode value even i use nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode, triggers

I'm trying to create a `stored procedure` that can add new member (using email and pass) work with a trigger that check if that email has already been used or not, problem is my SP cant store unicode(my understanding is other language is called unicode)

I've tried using N' in

```
insert into member (email,pass)
    values (N'@email',N'@pass')
```

as i saw on the Internet but it doesn't work

```
alter procedure addmember
@email nvarchar(40),
@pass nvarchar(12)
as 
     begin
        insert into member (email,pass)
    values (@email,@pass)
    end

    alter  trigger checkaddmember on member
    instead of insert
    as
    begin
    declare @email nchar(40),
    @pass nvarchar(12),
    @memid int

    select @email = email, @pass = pass, @memid = memberid
    from inserted
    .....

        end
    else 
    begin
    insert into member (email,pass)
    values (@email,@pass)
    set @memid = @@identity

end
end
```

I want a result to be something like

```
Email         ๆไกห <- unicode(Thai language)   

Password       blahblah
```

What i got is sth. like ??????????? as an output even i drop that trigger my SP wouldnt stored an unicode my exec would be exec admember @email = '' ,@pass ="

Comment: *Can* you alter a trigger inside a stored procedure?  Why would you want to?  What is the trigger supposed to be doing?

Comment: Start over. Forget the trigger for now - that is likely a path you don't need nor will it be successful. Now, write the stored procedure to do whatever it is you want to accomplish for the task of "adding a member". Most likely the problem you are having is related to how you / your code executes the procedure. That code you did not provide.

Comment: How is table Member defined?  Are fields email and pass nvarchar?

Comment: You tell us the desired result.  What result are you getting?

Comment: What i got is sth. like ???????????  as an output

even i drop that trigger my SP wouldnt stored an unicode

my exec would be 
exec admember @email = '' ,@pass ="